# How to fetch data from API in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api, remote-server

I am trying to fetch data from remote server and returning in alertbox using react-native.

Here's my code for fetching:

```
_onPressButtonPOST: function(){
    fetch("http://www.example.com/endpoint", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      key: "value",
    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    Alert.alert(
              "POST Response",
              "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData.body)
          )
  })
  .done();
  },
```

Here is what i want to fetch from my endpoints.

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "service",
        "_type": "service",
        "_id": "ac8c5edd-1aad-406f-b476-012c6e940c1a",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "service_owner_id": "2",
          "service_name": "miamia",
          "service_email": "mk@gmail.com",
          "service_contact_name": "mukesh",
          "service_landline_number": "12345",
          "service_mobile_number": "1234567890",
          "service_address": "vdvml",
          "service_listingType": 1,
          "service_avg_rating": 3.5,
          "sarvice_ratingcount": 10,
          "service_serviceType": 1,
          "service_working_hour": [
            ""
          ],
          "service_subcat_ids": "2,3",
          "service_description": "hi I am mukesh kumar ",
          "service_id": "ac8c5edd-1aad-406f-b476-012c6e940c1a",
          "service_logo_url": "",
          "service_gallery_url": "",
          "service_location": {
            "lat": 19.34,
            "lon": 72.845
          },
          "service_subcategory": "CAT GER ",
          "service_review": []
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false
}
```

But in alertbox it is showing undefined what might be the issue? Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Try logging responseData.body and check if it has a value

Comment: i tried using console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body)) but could not find anything

Comment: I meant do this .then((responseData) => console.log(responseData.body) and then check in your dev tools log

Comment: Its coming "undefined" there also whenever i click on button the count of undefined increases what might be the cause for it?

Comment: I think responseData is null

Comment: So can you tell me whether the problem is with fetch url or the responseData.body? What does body stand for?

Comment: I also have problems with fetch since I upgraded from 0.27. Fetch fails on my Simulator, but works fine on device. I suspect that it has something todo with this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8419

Comment: Update: Sorry - doesnt work on my device either.

Comment: hey @ThorbenA do i need to connect my app to internet to use fetch?

Comment: hey guys i have updated my question with my JSON data from the endpoint so can you tell what might be the issue with responseData.body?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i found out the bug and consumed the API successfully thanks to https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/make-http-requests-in-ios-with-react-native/ 
I just replaced responseData.body with responseData as there was no body included in my server side code so it was returning undefined

Here is my sample code

```
.then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    Alert.alert(
              "POST Response",
              "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
          )
  })
  .done();
```

Any doubts and queries are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Generally another reason is that, in PHP endpoint code they try to fetch the parameters sent by using $_POST, $_GET or $_REQUEST.

In that case, instead of Json, use FormData as body's value in your fetch operation.

An example

```
        var FormDataToPost = new FormData();
        FormDataToPost.append('userId', 12);

        fetch(url, { 
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                    },
                body: FormDataToPost
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => { do something })
            .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error);
             })
            .done();
```